# How to use Latex with knitr on online editor

Tags: overleaf, knitr

I am having troubles with R code. I want to write my bachelor's thesis and I do it in R.
Since I am using R, I use knitr package & format and I also use Overleaf as editor + .tex (LaTeX) code, not R Markdown.

I know that Overleaf lets me to import basic packages such as ggplot2, shape, etc, but I have import from different popular packages which Overleaf doesn't recognize.
I want to write R code that imports libraries not so known, but I can't do it in Overleaf, even if I would want to.

My question is the following: Can I write R code and import different libraries in Overleaf in order to run properly? I tried using "read_chunk" method but it doesn't work, also with many other options, but I can't get it to work. If it's not working, is there a workaround for this problem?

Thank you for your attention and I hope you can help me.

Comment: If the R library is not available on Overleaf, you cannot solve this by installing it yourself: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66368659/. Your only option then is to use a local installation of R and LaTeX. If you don't want to do a full LaTeX installation (TexLive or MikTeX), you can do a minimal installation with the R package TinyTex. If you use TinyTex, which is very good, you will spend time adding missing packages e.g. pgf. So TinyTex comes with a maintenance overhead, which a full installation of TexLive and MikTex don't have. Write your thesis. Don't mess with software installations.

Comment: @Ross thanks for the advice! Much appreciate it.